# Deploy MVC .NET app from Visual Studio to AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, publish, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an MVC app and I want to deploy it to an existing Elastic Beanstalk instance.
I want to do it using the zip uploading feature.
What should I put on the zip?

a)The published app

b)The full web deploy package in a zip?

c)Or other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **AWS Toolkit for Visual studio**. It has to be a non-express edition because it doesn’t work on other distributions.